# Finding duplicates in a Column using sql joins

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, duplicates

Actually i had posted this question before. But didn't got a quite good solution, so i deleted the old one. Iam posting it again here.

Please take a look at my table. In the dateofbirth field there are 2 pairs of similar dateofbirths.

> http://s24.postimg.org/cejm8ocqd/ello.jpg

Now the question is 'how can i return the name of the students that born on the same day'.

When i posted this question other day i got a solution by using partition, one of my friend told me he thinks it is possible using joins. i want to know if it is possible using 'SQL JOINS' then which join is used (self join?), why it is used, and a good explanation about the code you have written. i mean explaining each and every line, as iam a beginner in sql, so that i can understand it easily.

I dont want complicated explanations or code, i want the simplest basic way it can be done. I want to learn it from basics.

Comment: Its not homework. Its a set of 50 questions given by our trainer last week. its a beginner series like the basic stuffs in the set. I did all the intermediate questions (mostly using Inner join), since this is a single table. i searched a lot about self join and found many answers but for this question it quite hard to understand. Also i didnt quite get what self join really means. Hows it work, hows it usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way for me is the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students
INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT stu_dateofbirth 
          FROM Students 
          GROUP BY stu_dateofbirth 
HAVING Count(stu_dateofbirth 
         ) > 1) AS DateOfBirths
ON Students.stu_dateofbirth = DateOfBirths.stu_dateofbirth
```

The join is on a select statement that gets any date of births that appear more than once, you then join this on the main table date of birth column to retrieve all students that match the date of births.

There are lots of ways but the above acheives it using a join so hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the reply paul. can i also know other techniques to find it too. please provide explanations like above.